# Reloading Options with reloadOnChange in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

In my ASP.NET Core application I bind the appsettings.json to a strongly typed class *AppSettings*.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);
    //...
}
```

In a singleton class I wrap this AppSettings class like this:

```
public class AppSettingsWrapper : IAppSettingsWrapper
{
    private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _options;

    public AppSettingsAdapter(IOptions<AppSettings> options)
    {
        _options = options ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Options cannot be null");
    }

    public SomeObject SomeConvenienceGetter()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Now I'm struggling with reloading the AppSettings if the json file changes. I read somewhere that the class *IOptionsMonitor* can detect changes but it doesn't work in my case.

I tried calling the *OnChange* event like this for testing purposes:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder, IOptionsMonitor<AppSettings> optionsMonitor)
{
    applicationBuilder.UseStaticFiles();
    applicationBuilder.UseMvc();

    optionsMonitor.OnChange<AppSettings>(vals => 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vals);
    });
}
```

The event is never triggered when I change the json file. Has someone an idea what I can change to get the reloading mechanic to work in my scenario?

Comment: This feels like a bug. If you are adding a json file and want a reload call on change, then saving a change to the file should call any change handlers and set haschanged to true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to inject `IOptionsSnapshot<AppSettings>` to get the reload working.

Unfortunately you cannot load the `IOptionsSnapshot` into a Singleton service. `IOptionsSnapshot` is a Scoped service so you can only reference it in a Scoped or Transient registered class.

But, if think about it, that makes sense. The settings need to be reloaded when they change so if you inject them into a Singleton then the class will never get the updated settings because the constructor will not be called again for a Singleton.

Comment: I thought that I maybe could rebind the AppSettingsWrapper with the new AppSettings in the "OnChange" event. It is unfortunate that I have to change the lifetime of my wrapper class because besides the rare reloading it never changes.

Comment: Unless you have a really compelling reason to keep it as a singleton e.g. real time performance, switching to a `Scoped` service should give you what you want without much penalty, after all you are still injecting the same class, only the registration has changed.

Comment: Nothing stopping you creating a scope inside your singleton using IServiceProvider.CreateScope.

Comment: What is the purpose of reloadOnChange if it doesn't ping the change handles when the config source (in this case a file) changes?

Comment: You completely ignore IOptionsMonitor in your answer. According to the documentation, this one is supposed to be able to detect changes being a singleton. Perfect! Would be... if it worked...

Answer (score 18):

What you can do is create your wrapper class around the config class like you did in **AppSettingsWrapper** and inject IOptionsMonitor. Then keep a private property of your settings class. That wrapper can be injected as a singleton and the IOptionsMonitor will keep track of your changes.

```
public class AppSettingsWrapper
{
    private AppSettings _settings;

    public AppSettingsWrapper(IOptionsMonitor<AppSettings> settings)
    {
        _settings = settings.CurrentValue;

        // Hook in on the OnChange event of the monitor
        settings.OnChange(Listener);
    }

    private void Listener(AppSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    // Example getter
    public string ExampleOtherApiUrl => _settings.ExampleOtherApiUrl;
}
```

Then register your wrapper class as a singleton

```
services.AddSingleton(sp => new AppSettingsWrapper(sp.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<AppSettings>>()));
```

Comment: Does this need FluentAssertions to be installed?

Comment: As far as I can remember this doesn't has any dependency on FluentAssertions.

Comment: For anyone else wondering, you do not need to push the service provider, you can simply register it as a singleton as so: `services.AddSingleton<AppSettingsWrapper>()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a singleton `IHostedService` which is, e.g., registered as singleton and the `Execute` method is triggered repeatedly by a timer + you want a new `IOptionsSnapshot` on each trigger, you can use the following code:

```
public MyHostedService (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}

private void ExecutedByTimer ()
{
    using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    var options = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<MyHostedServiceOptions>>().Value;
    // Voila, options is an up-to-date snapshot
}
```