# Why is not injected last version of configuration (appsettings.json)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, appsettings

I am trying to edit `appsettings.json` in runtime. 
I found great solution how to update this file:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45986656/9684060

I did everything according to answer above:

1) Added `MySettings` to DI container  (`MySettings` are added via `AddTransient`)
 services.ConfigureWritable(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MySettings)));

2) Constructor injection

```
    private readonly IWritableOptions<MySettings> _cfg;

    public MyController(IWritableOptions<MySettings> cfg)
    {
        _cfg = cfg;
    }
```

Then I use it in my `Create` controller action.

```
public ActionResult Create(string value)
    {

           //Some specific code...

            MyCustomObj myObj = new MyCustomObj(value);

            //Update appsettings
            _cfg.Update(opt =>
            {
                opt.MyCollection.Add(myObj);
            });

            //Some specific code...

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Overview));

    }
```

Configuration file is updated (updated `MySettings` object is serialized to file), but after redirection to `Overview` I have same collection without newly created object (Configuration without updated collection is injected into controller's constructor). 
I have to refresh page again and then I see updated configuration (Updated `MySettings` is injected).

I had suspect that it could be fault of [IOptionsSnapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptionssnapshot-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) interface, because it is scoped service. But scoped service should be alive only for the live time of the request and redirection is new request or am I wrong?

Same situation is when I try to delete some object from my collection.
Page with all items (included deleted one) is rendered. Everything is ok when I refresh page.

Comment: See this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097425/reloading-options-with-reloadonchange-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: I am registering `IWriteableOptions<T>` as  Transient. So this shouldn't be problem or Am I wrong?

`services.AddTransient<IWritableOptions<T>`

Comment: U ever found a solution to this? I have the same problem :)

Comment: Unfortunately no :(