# ASP Net Core 3.1. Set Identity options dynamically

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identity

In my application I would like to set the "RequireConfirmedAccount" option when the user logs in to true/false dynamically as an admin, basically activate/deactivate the requirement during runtime, without restarting the application.

Furthermore, potentially would like to be able to change any settings configured in the "ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)" dynamically.

Is this possible?

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // add feature management control
            services.AddFeatureManagement();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 3;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

                // **would like to turn this off or on dynamically**
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;

            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders(); token
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Following the link given in the comments below this is what I have:

appsettings.json

```
{
"AllowedHosts": "*",

  "AppSettings": {
    "RequireEmailConfirmation": "true"
  }
}
```

in Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();
            Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(appSettings);

             services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 3;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = bool.Parse(Configuration["AppSettings:RequireEmailConfirmation"]);
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            ...........
            
            services.AddSingleton(sp => new AppSettingsWrapper(sp.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<AppSettings>>()));
        }

}
```

in AppSettings.cs

```
public class AppSettings
    {
        public string RequireEmailConfirmation { get; set; }
    }
```

in AppSettingsWrapper.cs

```
 public class AppSettingsWrapper 
    {
        private AppSettings _settings;

        public AppSettingsWrapper(IOptionsMonitor<AppSettings> settings)
        {
            _settings = settings.CurrentValue;

            settings.OnChange(Listener);
        }

        private void Listener(AppSettings settings)
        {
            _settings = settings;
        }

        // Example getter
        public string RequireEmailConfirmation => _settings.RequireEmailConfirmation;
    }
```

SwitchViewModel.cs class

```
public class SwitchViewModel
    {     
        public string SwitchName { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }

        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    }
```

in SwitchBoardController.cs
(This controller will receive some values from multiple checkboxes from the view, turning some settings on or off in the app. Right now there is only one checkbox in the view for RequireEmailConfirmation for login. So the List contains just one item.)

> How do I use the wrapper class in this controller how do I inject it
> and use?

```
public class SwitchBoardController : Controller
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;      
        public SwitchBoardController(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;         
        }
        
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            var vm = new List<SwitchViewModel>();

            SwitchViewModel svm = new SwitchViewModel()
            {
                SwitchName = AppConstants.Constants.SWITCH_REQUIRE_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION,             
                IsSelected = bool.Parse(_config["AppSettings:RequireEmailConfirmation"])
            };

            vm.Add(svm);

            return View(vm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(List<SwitchViewModel> vm)
        {
            foreach (SwitchViewModel item in vm)
            {
                if (item.SwitchName == AppConstants.Constants.SWITCH_REQUIRE_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION)
                {
                   
                    _config["AppSettings:RequireEmailConfirmation"] = ( item.IsSelected ? "true" : "false");
                }
            }

            return View(vm);
        }
}
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097425/reloading-options-with-reloadonchange-in-asp-net-core

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Yes it did! I made it work, thank you very much.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen actually I could swear it worked, but trying again later on it seems it actually does not work... I am updating my question.

Comment: but I am sure this is the right path, just missing using that wrapper class properly in the controller I think.

Comment: In your case the easy solution should work fine: Use IOptionsSnapshot<> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-ioptionssnapshot-to-read-updated-data The linked post contains both, this standard solution and the "special wrapper" solution that you need IF (and only if) you want to consume your options inside of singleton services. Controllers are not singleton.